# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE functions.php

Tags: php, syntax-error

When we connect to our website we have the error since yesterday:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homez.534/planetinm/www/wp-content/themes/ut-gogreen/functions.php on line 301
```

Here is the line 301, could somebody tell me where is the syntax error?

```
<input type="text" id="col_<?php echo $i; ?>_title" name="col_<?php echo $i; ?>_title" style="width:350px;" value="<?php echo get_option('col_'$i'_title'); ?>" />
```

and I think we have also an error in line 307:

```
<textarea id="col_<?php echo $i; ?>_content" name="col_<?php echo $i; ?>_content" style="width:350px;"><?php echo get_option('col_'$i'_content'); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You error is here:

```
<?php echo get_option('col_'. $i. '_title'); ?>
```

You forgot to concatenate the strings with `$i`.

Answer (score 1):

Line 301:

```
value="<?php echo get_option('col_'$i'_title'); ?>"
```

Should be

```
value="<?php echo get_option('col_' . $i . '_title'); ?>"
```

You forgot the `.` operator, to concatenate string.

Same deal with 307:

```
<?php echo get_option('col_'$i'_content'); ?>
```

Should be

```
<?php echo get_option('col_' . $i . '_content'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! amazing how fast you were guys!!!

Comment: @user1584239 Please accept an answer when it solves your problem.

Comment: @SiGanteng I have edited your post. Contact should be "" . $variable.""

Comment: @KarmicDice your edit isn't correct..

Comment: @SiGanteng Ok. I didn't try it though ;) My mates agreed with me but, we are bit lazy to try it out. Hope, you did :)

Comment: Your comment was "Made a syntax error after the line : Should be . Did a proper concat", please don't make such comment without actually testing and getting a syntax error.